# Как перенести XAMPP сервер на реальный хостинг и требования к нему?

Tags: apache, php, mysql

Добрый вечер!
Я создал небольшой сервер на XAMPP и все протестировал на localhost, теперь я хочу перенести его на какой нибудь хост чтобы проверить в бою!
Интересует как это сделать, может есть инструкции? Какие возможности должны быть у хостинга и может вы посоветуете какой нибудь хост с бесплатным тестовым периодом, чтобы я мог это проверить?

Настраивал базу через phpMyAdmin, запущены для работы apache и MySQL.

Скрин, если о чем то говорит:

[image]

Спасибо!

Comment: скрин сюда можно было вставить, в виде картинки.

Comment: Нельзя и меня рейтинг ниже 60(

Comment: Самое простое - купить VDS с виндой, упаковать ваш C:\xampp и развернуть на сервере.

Перенос на простой shared-хостинг описать сложннее и процесс может зависить от вашего хостера. В целом нужно по-отдельности забэкапить и перенести базу данных (у хостеров обычно тоже есть phpMyAdmin), перенести содержимое c:\xampp\htdocs (обычно легче всего по FTP) перепроверить параметры соединения с БД (MySQL может физически находиться на другом сервере и сама база будет назваться согласно праилам именования у хостера).

Comment: Ну для начало нужно заказать место на хостинге(потому что провайдер даёт данные которые нужно потом будет ввести), потом перекинуть через FTP файлы. [Пример](http://bitte.net.ua/blog/kak-zalit-sayt-na-hosting/).